# What is the correct way to input # in a markdown

Tags: markdown

I don't know if this is the correct place to ask my question.

Actually my question is very simple. How to input # in my markdown document. Because # is always interpreted as something else, for example, header. I have no way to input the character '#' itself. Can anybody tell me how to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape it with a '\' as you normally would such characters - i.e. `\#` - see [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash)

Comment: [link to escaping docs](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want.